# Facebook share button on android issue

Tags: android, facebook, hyperlink, share

I have a web page that contains a Facebook share button.
The link it shares is in following format:

www.example.com/index?id=1234&info=56789

This link is shared using Facebook plugin share button. On desktop browsers it works fine but on Android (chrome browser), when clicking the share button , the Facebook app is opened and only "www.example.com/index?id=1234" part of the link is sent to the app for sharing.

I replaced the "&" with "%26" and it fixed it, but it breaks when sharing using on desktop.

Did any one had the same problem and know the solution for this?

Comment: Are you doing this in your own WebView?  Please be specific, it's not clear at all where this link is, how you're populating it, and if this even has anything to do with an Android app you're writing.

Comment: Sorry about the confusions. I edited the post

Comment: This sounds like a bug, you might want to report it in www.facebook.com/bugs.